# Save IMAP mail attachment to file server, and replace with link

Tags: php, email, imap, attachment

I have an issue. One user on our mail server is using his IMAP account as his cloud file storage. Normally this wouldn't be a problem, *but that user happens to be the **CEO***. It's a property development / management company, and he receives Gigs of plans and drawings a month. His mailbox is getting out of hand...

I need to try and detach the attachments, save them to our file servers, and replace the attachment reference with a link to the newly saved file.
This sounds like a feasible solution to the problem, but is it possible?
Bearing in mind that if I balls this up it could be terminal from a career point of view.

I'd be using PHP, and I can handle the saving of the files OK, it's just the replacement issue. Because of the way he works (his email is his file index), the attachments need to be linked from the original messages and available across his devices.

Is this doable?

Danny

Answer (score 0):

To make it functional from the outside, it would need to be placed on a publicly available server, which would result in security complications.

If the CEO's usage of this disk is that significantly bothering, you should probably insist that he adds storage to the machine, possibly exclusively for his own mailbox.

I don't see any benefit in moving a file from one machine to another because it takes a lot of space, especially considering the development and support of your custom solution.

Comment: Good point re the security. It's not something I'd considered. Having his latest plans turn up in a Google search could be just as terminal as breaking his mail system.
As we are just a small company we are reaching the limits of our internal infrastructure, so would need to outsource. This would involve migrating nearly 50GB of data in deeply nested directories to a new host. I was looking at it from a developer perspective, but perhaps I should just pass the buck to the SysAdmin.

Comment: There would be ways to secure it but probably no way to justify the work needed and the overhead it would add.